# Getting Http 500 error when calling QnA api with strictfilter

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am getting Http 500 error whenever i am calling the QnAMaker Api with Metadata(strictFilter) body. Am I not following any instruction before calling Apis?

QnA maker api is working perfectly  if I am not adding strictFilter in the Api request body.

api request details:

```
URL: https://qnamaker endpoint/qnamaker/knowledgebases/KBID/generateAnswer

Method: POST

content-type: application/json

Authorization: EndpointKey Key

Body:
{
  "question": "hi",
  "top": 3,
  "strictFilters": [
    {
      "name": "category",
      "value": "pears"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have even read the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage) 
Still no luck for me here.

QnaMaker Response Error with StrictFilter screenshot

[image: X]

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you get a solution?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh : Yeah, after publishing the KB again, Its worked for me.